# Validar campos em branco

Tags: java, android, validação

Estou com um formulário com 3 campos a serem preenchidos e armazenados em banco. Um dos campos é preenchido pelo sistema o restante pelo usuário.

```
boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editNome.getText().toString(),
                                editVeiculo.getText().toString(),
                                editVelmax);
```

Conforme acima, criei uma variavel boolean com nome isInserted para retornar verdadeiro ou falso, mas como a variavel **editVelmax** é sempre preenchida ele sempre está retornando verdadeiro mesmo os campos **editNome** e **editVeiculo** em branco. Como eu faço para fazer a validação também desses dois campos?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

Verifique os valores antes de persistir a informação:

```
boolean isInserted = false;
String nome = editNome.getText();
String veiculo = editVeiculo.getText();

if(nome != null && veiculo != null && !nome.trim().isEmpty() && !veiculo.trim().isEmpty()){
     isInserted = myDb.insertData(nome, veiculo, editVelmax);
}
```